# Why haxelib will not install flixel library

Tags: windows-10, installation, command-prompt, haxe, haxeflixel

**Issue:** I cannot install any libraries using Haxe. **Purpose:** I want to install HaxeFlixel.

---

*(Note: I am a newbie when it comes to using the command prompt for installing files, and it was run as administrator).*

I have installed haxe 4.0.2 (with neko), located in C:\HaxeToolkit (seems to be Haxe 3.4.0 instead).

`> haxelib` returns usage info options.

`> haxelib install all` returns,

`No hxml files found in the current directory`. Seems like I'm missing files.

`> haxelib install flixel` returns

`Error: Failed with error: X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed`.

---

I also tried installing a different version of Haxe that is compatible with a specific version of Flixel. Unfortunately the same error appears and more.

- downloaded Flixel 4.6.3 (It's haxelib.json file says `"releasenote": "Compatibility with Haxe 4.0.0-rc.3"`).
- uninstalled Haxe 4.0.2 and downloaded and installed Haxe 4.0.0-rc.3 (seems to be Haxe 3.4.0 instead, again)
- placed Flixel folder in HaxeToolkit\haxe.
- `> haxelib install flixel` returns

```
Error: haxelib Repository C:/WINDOWS/system32/flixel does not exist. Please run `haxelib setup` again.

Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 1149
Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 1143
Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 1672
Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 467
```

`> haxelib setup` returns

`Please enter haxelib repository path with write access`

`> C:/WINDOWS/HaxeToolkit` returns

`haxelib repository is now C:\WINDOWS\HaxeToolkit`

`> haxelib install flixel` returns

```
Error: X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed

Called from haxe/remoting/HttpConnection.hx line 63
Called from C:\projects\haxe\std/sys/Http.hx line 58
Called from C:\projects\haxe\std/sys/Http.hx line 245
Called from C:\projects\haxe\std/sys/Http.hx line 60
Called from haxe/remoting/HttpConnection.hx line 64
Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 51
Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 721
Called from haxelib/client/Main.hx line 470
```

Again flixel did not install.

---

Any help to clarify what might be going wrong is appreciated.

Comment: These steps fixed my issue: 
1. Download Haxe https://haxe.org/download/ and install to C:\Dev\. 2. Download Flixel https://lib.haxe.org/p/flixel/ to Downloads. 3. Switch cmd directiory to Downloads `>cd C:\Users\User\Downloads`. 4. Install Flixel zip `>haxelib install "flixel-4,6,3.zip"`. 
Done.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Flixel is compatible with the latest stable Haxe release 4.0.5, so you shouldn't downgrade to an older version.

It sounds like you installed Haxe to `C:/WINDOWS/HaxeToolkit`? I'm not sure that's a good idea, since `C:\WINDOWS` is a system folder. Also, `haxelib setup` should probably not point to the `HaxeToolkit` folder directly - by defalt it uses a `lib` subfolder (`C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\lib\`).

All that being said, to work around the `haxelib install` issues, you could download the libraries you need as .zip files from the Haxelib website, e.g. https://lib.haxe.org/p/flixel/ for Flixel:

[image]

You can then run `haxelib install` on the file (first switch to your `Downloads` folder with `cd`):

```
>haxelib install "flixel-4,6,3.zip"
Installing flixel...
  Current version is now 4.6.3
Done
```

You would have to do this for all libraries that you need (`openfl`, `lime`, possibly `flixel-addons`, `flixel-templates` and `flixel-tools`).

Comment: Thankyou very much. Your answer fixed my issue. You addressed the mistakes I made (don't downgrade haxe, don't set repos to C:/WINDOWS, haxelib setup points to folder \lib, switching cmd directory with cd, and how to install a zip directly).

Answer (score 1):

install git from [here](https://git-scm.com/) if you don't have it then run

`haxelib git flixel https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel master`