# Unable to install Haxelib Flixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I am trying to download source code for a project, and it requires a list of installations for "HaxeFlixel". However, when I attempt to install Filxel in the command prompt. It states the following:

C:\Users\mimin>haxelib install flixel
Downloading flixel-5,0,2.zip...
Failed to download https://lib.haxe.org:443/files/3.0/flixel-5,0,2.zip. (1/3)
Failed to write to C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip: [file_open,C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip]
Failed to download https://lib.haxe.org:443/files/3.0/flixel-5,0,2.zip. (2/3)
Failed to write to C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip: [file_open,C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip]
Failed to download https://lib.haxe.org:443/files/3.0/flixel-5,0,2.zip. (3/3)
Failed to write to C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip: [file_open,C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip]
Error: [file_open,C:/Program Files/haxe/lib/flixel-5,0,2.zip]

I'm not entirely sure what I did wrong. But I've been sitting in my desk for a while confused on what to do.

I attempted to type in "haxelib install flixel" in order to install Flixel. Every other program I've installed this way worked but for flixel it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have permissions to write in folder or can't download. Try to download lib manually https://lib.haxe.org/files/3.0/flixel-5,0,2.zip
Or try to [download and install flixel lib manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987695).